# In SAS, calculate value using conditional logic with different variables

Tags: selection, sas, calculated-columns

I have some individual health data, and I need to calculate the average blood pressure reading from a set of four individual readings.  However, there are conditional rules that have to be followed to calculate the average.  I am using four readings of systolic blood pressure (`s1, s2, s3` and `s4`). The rules are as follows:

1. if `s4` is missing, then the blood pressure reading is (s1+s2)/2
2. if `s4` is **not** missing and s2, s3, and s4 are equidistant apart, average the largest two values of s2, s3, and s4.
3. if `s4` is **not** missing and s2, s3, and s4 are **not** equidistant apart, average the two values that are the closest together.

I've considered using arrays and proc transpose, but was wondering if there was a more elegant way to approach this problem.

Sample data is included below:

---

```
data bp;
input id s1 s2 s3 s4;
cards;
001              140            147            145            143
002              136            135            126            130
004              168            152            156              .
005              137            138            137              .
006              156            154            155              .
007              138            146            134            138
012              127            133            135              .
013              112            112            100             88
017              127            122            126              .
019              137            138            150            135
020              109            118            113            116
021              112            112            109            107
022              119            136            129            130
026              119            108            116            118
027              126            120            130            123
028              143            143            135            139
029              144            143            117            137
030              116            114            108            110
032              135            146            139            134
041              128            128            132              .
run;




data bp_2; set bp_1;

 s_dif2 =    abs(s3-s2) ;
 s_dif3 =    abs(s4-s3) ;

run;
```

---

The first condition is pretty easy to code, but I'm having trouble selecting values across variables in SAS.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put the variables into a temporary array and sort that array (`CALL SORTN`), allowing you to be sure which will be biggest/smallest.

```
data want;
set bp;
if missing(s4) then bp = (s1+s2)/2;
else do;
  array _s[4] _temporary_;
  array s[4];  *this stores s1,s2,s3,s4 into an array;
  do _t = 2 to dim(_s);
    _s[_t] = s[_t];
  end;
  call sortn(of _s[*]); *this sorts the _s array, and _s[1] will stay as missing.  That way we know where the smallest/largest are.;
  if abs(_s[2]-_s[3]) = abs(_s[3]-_s[4]) then bp = (_s[3]+_s[4])/2; *exactly equidistant - if you have some tolerance fix this if here;
  else if abs(_s[2]-_s[3]) < abs(_s[3]-_s[4]) then bp=(_s[2]+_s[3])/2;
  else bp = (_s[3]+_s[4])/2;
end;
run;
```

Comment: You, sir, are a rockstar!